# Scapy extract TCP window size

Tags: scapy, pcap

I wanted to know how to extract the TCP window size using Scapy

For example to get the IP packet payload I use the following code

`````
def packethandler(pkts):
         with codecs.open("Dropcam.csv", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for pkts in pkt:
            data = (len(pkts))
            data2 = (len(pkts.payload))
            ether_len.append(data)
            IP_len.append(data2)

            ethernet_header_min = min(ether_len)  # min ethernet frame length
            ethernet_header_max = max(ether_len)  # max ethernet frame length

````
`````

Comment: What do the [scapy docs](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) say on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

`pkt[TCP].window`